# Hard Disk Fragment Labels?

Tags: hard-drive

how are the blocks of information on a hard drives labeled?  do they follow a specific numbered scheme for each block?  if a hard drive is fragmented, what are the labels or addresses of the parts with information?  is it a simply numeric:  1, 2, 3, etc.?  or does it look something like:  0x1, 0x2, 0x3, etc.?  perhaps harddrive blocks all start with a prefix?

it's for a design project.  i have 10 horizontally aligned squares and i want to label them.  what should their labels look like?

Comment: There is no difference between "1, 2, 3" and "0x1, 0x2, 0x3". Both are numbers.

Comment: "Fragmented" means that there are small pieces of unallocated space between allocated pieces.  This can happen if you allocate two 10-block files, delete the first, and then allocate a 9-block file in its place.  The remaining 1 block is too small to be useful in most cases.  Has nothing to do with block numbering -- they could be numbered with Roman numerals and it would still be the same problem.  Has a little to do with track sizes, as often one cannot allocate "across" a track boundary.

Comment: And what you call your squares will have no effect on disk fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know about how hard drive blocks are addressed, check Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector

The examples you give are just decimal and hexadecimal numbers. They are not specific to hard-drives. The 0x notation is just a way to denote hex numbers in code.

I'm not a designer, but if you're looking for the simplest thing that works, use decimal numbers zero through 9 to number your squares.  That gives you the bonus of being compatible with any numbering system with a base greater than or equal to 10.